# Objective-C / Cocoa bridge in PHP?

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa, macos, compiler-construction

Is there any good Objective-C or Cocoa Bridge/Connector for PHP? I'm interested in Mac development, but want to do it with PHP. It'd be also good if you could recommend me any PHP compiler for Mac.

Note: I already know [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)-like apps, and that's not what I want.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not learn the actual language? The performance gain, features gain and knowledge gain is awesome, do not be scared of trying new things, enrich your world ! ^^

Comment: Even using a bridge, you'll still have to understand and be able to read Objective-C. The Cocoa frameworks and docs are written in that language, and they are tightly tied to the idioms of the language. I'm not saying you shouldn't use a bridge -- I love PyObjC -- just be aware that it's not as simple as "Use PHP to write Mac apps".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's one here: http://www.slideshare.net/wezfurlong/hot-chocolate-you-got-cocoa-in-my-php

(download link is in the slides)

There's little in PHP that is going to do you any favors with Mac development, though.  If you want to do Mac development with a language that has a more familiar syntax and you don't want to deal as much with memory issues and such, doing your coding with MacRuby or RubyCocoa shouldn't be too much of a jump from previous PHP experience.

Comment: I'm actually learning Ruby and Rails now. About the slide, I've already seen it and it seems discontinued or unavaliable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Great -- you won't need any of the Rails stuff for the Mac development, but the familiarity with Ruby syntax and best practices should make things easier for you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get the wezfurlong-Bridge running under Mac OS X Lion. So I decided to use the flexibility of Objective-C to let PHP talk to my Cocoa application, even create objects and send messages with arguments to them.
You can get the source including the (very basic) sample application on http://github.com/cundd/pop/

Answer (score 0):

I "bridge" PHP like this…  simplicity is golden..  If you wanna get fancy, JSON encode things back and forth, and send raw data as `base64` encoded strings…

```
- (NSString *)getSomethingFromPHP {
    NSString *scriptPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPHPscript.php"];
    NSString *standardIn = [myApp someData]
    NSTask *php  = [NSTask new];
    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe new]; 
    [php setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/php"];
    [php setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       @"-f", scriptPath, standardIn, nil]];
    [php setStandardOutput:pipe];       
    NSFileHandle *handle = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [php launch];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:
       [handle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
    return string;
}
```